# UIButton doesn't work (animation not played)

Tags: swift, uikit

I have some issue with my uiButton, it doesn't work and the animation is never played...
The UserInteractive is activate...
Can you help me? thanks a lot!
this is my code and my storyboard

```
   @IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: dataArray.count - 1, section: 0)
    dataArray.append(Task(task: "", button: false))
    self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

}
```

[soryboard Todolist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTEDJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the performBatchUpdates method from UICollectionView

```swift
@IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: dataArray.count - 1, section: 0)
    dataArray.append(Task(task: "", button: false))
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates ({
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

    }, nil)
```

If the action is not firing, you should check that you have wired up the IBAction to the correct control

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment!
the code works, but I can't click on the button.
for example, if I put a print, nothing append...